# Missing ";" before identifier "name" even though it's there

Tags: c++, syntax

Here is my code:

```
 #ifndef PROBLEM3_H
 #define PROBLEM3_H

 #include <string>

 struct stackItem {
     // arbritary name do define item
     string name;
 };

 class Hw3Stack {
     public:
         // Default constuctor that prompts the user for the stack
         // capacity, initalizes the stack with the capacity, and the sets
         // the size of zero.
         Hw3Stack();

         // Copy constructor that takes a current stack and copies the
         // current size, capacity, and stackItems into the current object.
         Hw3Stack(Hw3Stack& stack);

         // Destructor that deletes the stack
         ~Hw3Stack();

         // Returns true if there are no items in stack, false otherwise.
         bool isEmpty();

         // Returns the current size of Hw3Stack
         int getSize();

         // Returns the current capacity of the stack.
         int getCapacity();

         // Adds the stackItem to the stack. If the stack is equal to
         // the capacity after insertion, copy all of the current 
         // stackItems into a new array with double the current capacity
         // and set the current stack array to the new array.
         void push(stackItem item);

         // Removes the top stackItem. Returns true if sucessful. Returns 
         // false otherwise (i.e. if the stack is empty).
         bool pop();

         // Returns a reference to the top stackItem, but does not remove
         // the top stackItem. If empty, you may return nullptr.
         stackItem* top();

         // Prints the stack contents’ names from top to bottom.
         void printStack();

     private:
         int capacity; // capacity of the stack
         int size; // current size of the stack
         stackItem* stack; // pointer to the array stack
 };

 int problem3();

 #endif PROBLEM3_H
```

I'm getting the following errors:

error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'name'

error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int

I don't know what is going wrong here because I thought I wrote the code correctly. Visual Studio is not telling me there are any errors before compilation so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Also a good idea to use "typedef struct" - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/612328/difference-between-struct-and-typedef-struct-in-c

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use:

```
std::string name;
```